# Temporary washing machine installation

Tags: plumbing, flooring, waterproofing, water-damage, washer

I had a plumbing leak that took out my laundry room floor.  I had a custom ceramic tile floor that had a drain in the middle to catch leaks.  Now the floor is removed and I'm left with only the subfloor.  The drain is approximately 2 inches off of the floor.  I'm hesitant to run my washer without any sort of water protection on the floor in case of (another) leak.  I can get a washer drain pan but not sure if I can tie it into the existing drain (or if that matters).

Any thoughts how I can solve this problem?  Should I try to build a platform and raise the washer above the drain?

I'm scheduled for a new floor but it will be 2 months before installation.  I'd rather not modify the current drain until the long term floor gets installed.

[image]

Comment: Is this drain covered by the washer? If so, a simple platform would work temporarily. Keep in mind that washing machine leaks are relatively rare, but a pan/alarm system should take care of that.

Comment: If the sides of the drain pan are significantly higher than the top of the floor drain, then you can run the drain line from the pan to this drain. A couple of zip ties or similar jury-rigging to keep it in place should be sufficient for the short term, just remember to check on it each time you run the washer. Anything that does leak into the pan will be contained until enough water has collected that it pushes through the hose, up the hill and down the drain. Since the pan itself is higher than the drain, it'll hold the water.

Comment: I'm confused that your ceramic tile floor with floor drain was "taken out" by a leak? Isn't that (not being a problem) the whole point...?

Comment: You could babysit the washer while it works and read a book.  That might take as much time as jury rigging something.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I'll look into how tall the drain pan edges are but I don't think it will be high enough.  I'll probably get a water sensor and monitor during loads.  And yes, the old ceramic tile should have caught my leak.  But 30 years ago someone didn't caulk between the wall tile and the floor tile.  Water got behind and under the tile floor.

Comment: You don't need the drain unless your washer leaks. I have had three different washers over 25 years with no leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about location very much:
Buy 4 cinderblocks, a chunk of heavy plywood, a washer drain pan, and a hole saw.

Put the 4 cinder blocks down around the drain, then put the plywood on top, and the drain pan on top of that.  Drill a hole through the drain pan and plywood directly above the drain.  Now put the washer on in the drain pan, and zip tie the drain hose to the drain.

This is ugly, but it should work.

Comment: Would you be concerned that the washer would rock off the cinder blocks?  I thought about building a platform initially but figured if it rocked off one side and tipped I'd be much worse off.